# Why doesnt AfterFeature get called in SpecFlow when an Assert.Fail gets called in BeforeFeature

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a set of instructions set up in my SpecFlow test that runs in the BeforeFeature. However if one of those instructions fails then I call a Assert.Fail();

The problem is that if I do this the AfterFeature section does not run it simply just ends the test for the feature. This shouldn't happen the AfterFeature method should still get run. Does anyone have any guidance on how I can get around this?

More info:

I'm assigning user IDs from a login pool in the BeforeFeature, then de-assigning them in the AfterFeature.

Here is my code:

```
[BeforeFeature]
private static void BeforeFeature()
{
  //Assign the login ids
  if(someCondition)
  {
      //Pass assigned ID
  }
  else
  {
      //Failed to assign the Id
      Assert.Fail();
  }
}

[AfterFeature]
private static void AfterFeature()
{
 //release the ids
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you throw an exception rather than call `Assert.Fail`, does it behave the same way? Maybe there is a bug/feature in SpecFlow that prevents `AfterFeature` from executing when an error gets thrown in a `BeforeFeature`, because calling `Assert.Fail` essentially throws an exception.

Comment: I shall try that and report back Greg, thanks for the suggestion.